# Ubuntu Server 23.10: How to force a USB boot on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Tags: boot, server, usb

How can I setup my `Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W` to boot from USB in **Ubuntu Server** Linux distributions. I am looking for a solution that applies to all supported versions of Ubuntu Server, latest and below.

Turns out that not all the USB boot options work on `Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W` + Ubuntu Server and I have not find a solution that actually works. Therefore, I am posting it as a new question.